# Firebase - Concurrent Connections without Users being online

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I´m using the Firebase Realtime Database and Cloud Functions.
I´m testing my app with two users.

However, in my Database Usage Page it says that the maximum concurrent connections were 37. Also, it says that I had 8 simultaneous connections at a day on which I actually did not test my app at all.
How does this work? I´m familiar with the definition given in the Firebase FAQ.

Do cloud functions count to the connections as well?

Best regards